# how to get unique data which latest in SQL with JPA?

Tags: java, sql, spring, jpa

I have duplicate phone_id but have a different name, on my database I have 3 columns, phone_id, name, created_at

```
1. phone_id: 111, name: David, created_at: 10:30
2. phone_id: 122, name: Shinta, created_at: 7:10
3. phone_id: 111, name: Juan, created_at: 11:36
```

i do love to get only the last created_at

so the result is

```
phone_id: 111, name: Juan, created_at: 11:36
phone_id: 122, name: Shinta, created_at: 7:10
```

when I use :

```
*SELECT * FROM Contacts GROUP BY phone_id*
```

it gets the result David and Shinta because David created the first time, but that is the result I don't want

i want the result is Juan and Shinta
what is the syntax for to get unique based on last created ?

Comment: what is the `PK` in your table? you can generate an auto increment id as PK and order by that.

Comment: i have ID @user404

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
SELECT C.name, C.phone_id, C.created_at
FROM Contacts C, (SELECT phone_id, MAX(created_at) as created_at
    FROM Contacts
    GROUP BY phone_id) as C2
WHERE C.phone_id = C2.phone_id and C.created_at = C2.created_at
ORDER BY phone_id
```